# Hypernym for comparisons (less than / greater than)

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Question says it all, I'm looking for a Hypernym that groups ">" and "<" and perhaps similar logical comparators (">=") into a word. I'm not sure if "logical comparator" is even a valid term, and using it doesn't feel great either.

Comment: Your term *comparisons* seems to work as the hypernym you're looking for.

Comment: They are called [*relational operators*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator).

Comment: Thanks @Mick, if you make your comment into an answer I'll mark it as solved :)

Comment: The specific relationship is *ordering*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are known as *relational operators*.

> In computer science, a relational operator is a programming language construct or operator that tests or defines some kind of relation between two entities. These include numerical equality (e.g., 5 = 5) and inequalities (e.g., 4 ≥ 3).
>
> In programming languages that include a distinct boolean data type in their type system, like Pascal, Ada, or Java, these operators usually evaluate to true or false, depending on if the conditional relationship between the two operands holds or not. In languages such as C, relational operators return the integers 0 or 1, where 0 stands for false and any non-zero value stands for true.
>
> An expression created using a relational operator forms what is termed a relational expression or a condition. Relational operators can be seen as special cases of logical predicates.

[Wikipedia: Relational operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator)