# A single word to describe "less than" and "greater than"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

It is not about object being less than something and greater than something at the same time, but rather about property of object, the "ability" of object to be lesser or greater.

Context: I'm programmer and I need to give a name for data structure field. Value of this parameter can be either "less than" or "greater than".

Comment: Try ***inequality***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hypernym for comparisons (less than / greater than)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/422455/hypernym-for-comparisons-less-than-greater-than)

Comment: @Jim I was so desperate and was about to name it **less_or_greater**... **inequality** seems to be a good choice. My friendo also suggested **superiority**, but it doesn't "sound" right.

Comment: @Laurel TIL Hypernym, now I know now to google stuff like this. And yeah, **relation** might work as well, tnx

Comment: Just out of interest can the two values ever be equal or are they always different?

Answer (score 2):

This property is of great importance in mathematics and it is called  comparability ([ref.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparability)). It is nevertheless a term widely applicable ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/comparability?q=comparability)).